# Why isn't my db table showing up on Apache Superset?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, apache-superset

I'm trying to mess around with this csv I have on Apache Superset. I created an sqlite database and tried to upload the csv via superset and was getting no return in the table section. So instead, I created the table through python, reloaded and still see no tables in superset in my nav database.

here's my code:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('nav.db')

csvfile = 'nav.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
df.to_sql('nav', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

here's the sql URI I have set to my database in superset:

```
sqlite:////Users/name/path/superset/venv/nav.db
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the superset configuration file(config.py) to enable SQLite by setting.

```
PREVENT_UNSAFE_DB_CONNECTIONS = False
```